# Magento 2 is sending Emails in english if sent programmatically

Tags: php, email, magento, locale

I'm looking for hours now and I found some topics that are similar but none of them solved my issue.

I'm writing a Magento 2.3 Extension to import customers from a different Database. Everything works fine except for the email language.

I would expect Magento to use automatically the correct language (store config) when i'm sending the "New Account Email"

Here is the method I'm using to send the Email

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

If I send the "Password Reset" Email by clicking on the corresponding Button in the customer settings, Magento sends the Email in the correct language.

I tried different config settings and different ways of set the locale inside my import method. Obviously nothing worked.

Comment: To recap:
In this script, you have imported the customer (Does this include the customer's language?) it might be Magento being clever and sending it in the users language instead :)

Comment: @KasperFranz Thanks for the reply. I did not know customers can have custom language. But I have set the website ID

Comment: Have you verified it is sent from the right store? (e.g. do you have multiple stores?) - documentation https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/d1ebc176e164dbc69c698f13a37d998a48645dbf/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L763

Comment: Yes, I have a multistore setup. And also yes, the correct store is sending the Emails

Comment: Have you set the store id argument manually to test the behavior?

Comment: @revo yes, kind of. `$customer->setWebsiteId($storeID);` I've found out, that this is the right way to set the store id.  
EDIT: By changing it to the "correct" method `$customer->setStoreId($storeID); $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteID);` there is no difference

Comment: `sendNewAccountEmail()` also receives store id as the third parameter.

Comment: Ah. Good to know. Thanks. I‘ll try it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following worked:

```php
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeID);
```